# How to check with Java if a process is hanging?

Tags: java, process

I have two questions:

1. I want to check with a Java program if a process is hanging (that means, you can't do anything with it, like the "no response" messages on Windows, when even resizing the window is not possible). How can I do this? I searched through the internet in the past threee hours without finding a solution. Does someone know how to do this?
2. In case there is a solution for question 1, how can I test it? That means, how can I create a Java program that will be hanging? I already tried things like a while(true)-loop or combinations of Thread.sleep(), but that is no "real" hanging. I still can resize the GUI.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution only for windows, [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=360779) might help a little bit.

Comment: If there is no solution for Java, then I have another possibility: The process I want to check for hanging is the OpenOffice process "soffice.exe". I can try to convert a document to PDF with OpenOffice and if that is not done within a certain time it means that the process is hanging.